# Password not verified in QUickblox Chat

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am facing an issue in Quickblox chat. While connecting with user I am getting following error

```
<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/><text lang="en">Password not verified</text></failure>" UserInfo=0x1a4e8c00 {NSLocalizedDescription=<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/><text lang="en">Password not verified</text></failure>})
```

I have already logged in the app on login screen.

Can any one please help/suggest what I am doing wrong. Any idea or suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your QBUUser instance. which you are using in connect method of QBChat, has valid password in it.

Comment: OK, what pattern is okay?

Comment: What do you mean? Correct password should be in it.